# Change view controller cause reset changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have two view controller. On the Second controller I have a button which cause a UILabel to change from "larry" to the string "happy". If I press back, which take me to first view controller, and then forward, which take me to the second view controller (from the first view controller). I found that the UILabel change back to default, "larry". How do I make it so that when I change view controller, the changes and data doesn't get clear away.

Recap: How to make it so that every change in a view controller doesn't change back to default after changing to another view controller.

This doesn't only happen with UILable, it also happen with

```
self.loadPage.hidden = YES;
```

I also found out what I made to turn 'hidden' also appear back after I pressed back and forward.

Thank

Comment: Can you please post your code where you switches from first view controller to second

Comment: Can you  post more code , so that I can tell you the precise answer . Meanwhile you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is due to the fact that when you press the button a new instance of the second viewcontroller is created and that old one is destroyed.

If you want to persist the data while pressing the buttons, you need some way to store the information somewhere
there are some methods to got about it

1. You can use instance variables in both the classes to store the data temporarily and display them. You need to know the concept of protocols and delegates for this as well.
2. You can store the information in NSUserDefaults for some moment so that you can access it later on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is each time when you goes from first view controller to second, you are initialising a new instance of second view controller which brings back every values you changed to default values.

You need to save the values elsewhere and assign those values whenever control is switched from one view controller to another